# Using FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR and FILECONTENTS fails on to long path

Tags: c++, copy-paste, shell-namespace-extension

I hava an application that currently uses the Copy and Past API with `FILECONTENTS` and `FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR`.

This works normaly without a problem. Unfortunatly this approach fails if the path + the filename specified in `FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR` excedes the maximal path lenght.

I also have noticed that Outlook (which uses the same approach) has the same problem.

I'm working on an Windows Explorer Namespace Extension. Does someone know an alternative to this approach.

Comment: Can you describe more in detail how to do this? I only set the file name on the ```FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR```. I don't work with pathes. The copy operation is performed by the windows explorer.

Comment: Sorry, it does not look like extended-length paths will work with this API.